# VSCode Java UTF-8 does not print characters to the console

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with encoding Java System Output occurring only in Visual Studio Code.

Like you can see in the image below bullet print as ?

Eclipse and IntelliJ print the bullet point just fine.

My program is very simple:
[image]

**Things I have tried/checked:**

1. chcp:
   [image: List item]
2. UTF8 is set:
   [image]
3. I only have the Java Extension Pack by Microsoft installed.
4. It is a fresh new file created from VScode.
5. The chcp inside VSCode terminal is Active code page: 65001
   [image]

Comment: I am pretty sure the UTF8 you see in the bottom bar correspond to the current active source-file charset, not the console's one. A quick google-search found me a github thread including this comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19837#issuecomment-290843303. I suspect you put that in the `settings.json` file. Might wanna give that a try

Comment: Anyone else could guide me on what to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UTF-8` displayed in the lower right corner of VS code is the encoding format of the **current file**, not the encoding format of the terminal.

**You should check the encoding by typing `chcp` in the terminal of VS code.**

The encoding format of the terminal in vscode may be different from the system's **cmd** and **powershell** encoding.

So please check the encoding format in the terminal in **VS code**, not in the **cmd** or **powershell** window of the system

##### Here is my test display:

**my code:**

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("example ●");
    }
}
```

The encoding format of the system **cmd** window is `65001`

[image]

The encoding format of the system **powershell** window is `65001`

[image]

But the terminal encoding in vscode is `437`

[image]

Run the result directly ( *Can't display symbols* )

[image]

So you need to use `chcp 65001` to change the current terminal encoding format in VS code.

then run the code (  *success display symbol*)

[image]

***But this still has problems, every time you open a new terminal, you need to manually type the command `chcp 65001` to change the encoding format.***

I found a way in my constant search. Add the following configuration in **settings.json**:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-noexit", "chcp 65001"]
```

*A yellow squiggly line will appear indicating that this configuration is out of date and there are now new configuration commands. Never mind, this still works.* If you want to see the new configuration, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_terminal-profiles).

***Note:*** After adding this configuration, you need to **restart** VS code to take effect.

In this way, when you create a new terminal, you will automatically use the command `chcp 65001` to change the encoding to `65001`

[image]

**Now run the code directly, the symbols can be displayed**

[image]

Comment: I just checked the vscode terminal chcp and it says Active code page: 65001 and I still have the problem anything else I can check?

Comment: Can you provide the jdk version you are using? and the version number of vscode.

Comment: I have no idea what was the problem but I just reinstall vscode and now it is working

Comment: *"this configuration is out of date"* - you can see the new configuration in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74665369/2189130).