# How to fix Visual Studio Code distorting characters on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have problems with Swedish national characters when using Rust in Visual Studio Code in Windows 11. It can be shown with the following program:

```
fn main() {
let abc = " ååå
ööö
äää";
println!("<---{}--->", abc);
}
```

When the program is run from the command line using `cargo run`, the output is as follows:

```
<--- ååå
     ööö
     äää--->
```

Strangely, spaces are added at the beginning of lines 2 and 3. However, when the program is run in Visual Studio Code, the Swedish characters get distorted.

```
<--- ├Ñ├Ñ├Ñ
     ├╢├╢├╢
     ├ñ├ñ├ñ--->
```

How can I solve it? I work with text processing and this is a major problem.

**EDIT**: Since the problem doesn't appear on many systems, I add the technical data: Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621;
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.73.1 (user setup) Date: 2022-11-09 Chromium: 102.0.5005.167 Node.js: 16.14.2 Sandboxed: No.

Comment: Which operating system? Which version? Which shell? What do you mean with "run in VSCode"? Through the integrated shell? Through clicking the "run" button of rust-analyzer?

Comment: It works on my Windows 11 on Ubuntu 22.04 WSL on integrated bash and also when hitting the "run" button. It also works on my Windows11 native with built-in powershell and on built-in "cmd". It also works when I hit the "run" button of rust-analyzer. It even works in git-bash (nested in VSCode).

Comment: I tried every combination of OS/Shell/run method that I have available, and it works on all of them.

Comment: Which shell are you using in VSCode? Cmd? Powershell? Git Bash? Does it happen on all of those, or just on one specific one?

Comment: Does switching between software/hardware rendering change anything? (Settings -> Features -> Terminal -> Integrated: Gpu Acceleration)

Comment: *"Strangely, spaces are added at the beginning of lines 2 and 3."* - That shouldn't happen. See: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4013bdc7e2ef652904f895cc1f9ece9e

Comment: Did you try updating Rust to the newest version? (Don't think it will change anything, but it's worth at try)

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19837

Comment: Said thread suggests you add this to your vscode config (Settings->Click on top right button "Open Settings (JSON)"), then add this line if you are using CMD: `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "chcp 65001"],`. Alternatively, if you are using PowerShell, use this line: `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoExit", "/c", "chcp.com 65001"],`. Of course restart your VSCode in between. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Finomnis: see the technical data added to the question. I've tried both the commands in the VSC terminal but they produce error output `"Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement."`

Comment: They aren't supposed to go in your terminal, but in your VSCode settings page. Either way, they are deprecated. I added the new version in my answer.

Comment: Btw, your error output strongly indicates that you are using Powershell. CMD would say `'"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: @Finomnis: it is Powershell, I see it now.

Comment: Out of curiousity: You said it worked if you execute the program in the shell directly. Did it also work if you execute it in **Powershell** directly? Because I have a suspicion that the reason why it worked is that you used Powershell in VSCode, but CMD outside of VSCode.

Comment: @Finomnis: I used CMD outside VCS and Powershell inside VSC. I'm not sure what would have happen if I had run the program in Powershell outside VSC instead of CMD. The VCS settings are changed now so Powershell works certainly as well, I hope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**- This answer is Windows specific. -**

**INFO:** This answer describes you how can change your VSCode settings to force UTF-8 in your console. An alternative to this answer would be to force UTF-8 system-wide, as described here: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window)

---

It seems that sometimes the Windows shell doesn't use the correct UTF-8 code page.

You can tell VSCode to force a codepage in its shell using the following settings.

- Open the `Settings` page (Shortkey: `Ctrl+,`)
- Click on the button on the top right whose mouse-over text reads *"Open Settings (JSON)"*
- Add the following lines:

```
   "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [
                "-NoExit",
                "/c",
                "chcp.com 65001"
            ]
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [
                "/K",
                "chcp 65001"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
    },
```

This will force the `UTF-8` code page.

If it worked, opening a new shell should display `Active code page: 65001`.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19837

---

Previous, deprecated settings:

- If your shell is "CMD":

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "chcp 65001"],
  ```
- If your shell is "Powershell":

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoExit", "/c", "chcp.com 65001"],
  ```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!
If you can't find the button to open `settings.json` then hit <Ctrl>+<Shift>+<P> and type `settings.json` and select "Open User Settings (JSON)"

Comment: By the way did you manage to get colored text (ANSI color) working in the VSC terminal? I get colored output from the `log` crate with `cargo run` in a regular `cmd`, but not from within VSC. Although if I call `Get-PSReadLineOption` in the VSC terminal I see colored text so I wonder where the color information gets lost.

Comment: Color works for me, on Windows and on Linux. I use Git-Bash as my VSC terminal on windows, and regular console on Linux. But I also didn't require the fix discussed in my answer, it also defaulted to UTF-8. I still don't entirely understand when it is necessary and when not.

Comment: Weird. I don't even know how I should begin to debug the missing colors in the VSC terminal. Maybe it's easiest if I switch from the default powershell to Git-Bash as my VSC console like you. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well, that didn't work either. Git-Bash standalone works perfectly. But Git-Bash as VSC terminal just shows the raw color codes like `←[23m` instead of actually coloring the text output.